# Array To String while inserting data using insert_batch in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I am adding multiple rows in the database. 
I am using `insert_batch` in codeigniter.

**I see some of the SO questions but did not get  what I am doing wrong.**

I have created an array using `foreach`loop but get this error.

This is the `foreach`loop:

```
foreach($add as $data){
    $new_add[] = array(
        'col1'=>$data['col1'],
        'col2'=>$data['col2'],
        'col3'=>$data['col3'],
        'col4'=>$data['col4'],
        'col5'=>$data['col5'],
        'col6'=>$data['col6']
    );
}
```

After Loop This is the array which i got after it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [col1] => col1_data
            [col2] => col2_data
            [col3] => col3_data
            [col4] => col4_data
            [col5] => col5_data
            [col6] => col6_data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [col1] => col1_data
            [col2] => col2_data
            [col3] => col3_data
            [col4] => col4_data
            [col5] => col5_data
            [col6] => col6_data
        )

)
```

Insert Batch Query:

```
$this->db->insert_batch('test', $new_add);
```

> **Thanks To This Comment I have get what I am doing wrong. [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840326/array-to-string-while-inserting-data-using-insert-batch-in-codeigniter#comment76661402_44840326)**
>   I done a basic error here i want to use `insert_batch` but somehow I forgot to add this in the query.

The Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 1476
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   D:\opt\wamp\www\yo_builder\application\controllers\Instalment.php
>   Line: 85 Function: insert
>
> File: D:\opt\wamp\www\yo_builder\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

This is the Second Error.

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0, 1) VALUES (Array, Array)' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `test` (0, 1) VALUES (Array, Array)
>
> Filename: D:/opt/wamp/www/yo_builder/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I have added in the question. @KetanSolanki

Comment: post complete code

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Sir, nothing else to add here. I have added what i have done.

Comment: You are using insert as per your code in question. Use insert_batch

Comment: @hrishi Sir i am using insert batch already but forget to add in this question code. thx

Comment: Thanks @hrishi  It's just a simple **typo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the array like this :

```
$insertArray = array();
foreach($add as $data){
    $new_add = array(
        'col1'=>$data['col1'],
        'col2'=>$data['col2'],
        'col3'=>$data['col3'],
        'col4'=>$data['col4'],
        'col5'=>$data['col5'],
        'col6'=>$data['col6']
    );
   array_push($insertArray,$new_add);
}
```

And call the `insert_batch` like this :

```
$this->db->insert_batch('test', $insertArray);
```

And please verify that "col1","col2"... are valid column name of table "test".

Comment: I got it my foreach is working perfect. Error is that just i forget to add `insert_batch`  in the query. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you trying to insert arrays with different keys.
for example:

```
$data = [
  [
     "key1" => "value 1",
     "key2" => "value 2",
     "key3" => "value 3",
  ],
  [
     "key1" => "value 1",
     "key2" => "value 2"
  ]
];
```